# How to tell if/when you downloaded files from Dropbox or Google drive?

Tags: google-drive, dropbox

I am worried that, in general, there is another computer where I have not logged out of my Gmail or Dropbox.  I make it a habit to log out of my email regularly, but I could always have forgotten somewhere.  Thus, someone could easily download important files on my google drive and or Dropbox, if I didn't log out.

Is there a way to see on Google Drive or Dropbox if your files have been downloaded, and when?  I know Google drive and Dropbox tell when files have been UPLOADED.  How do you find if/when files have been downloaded?

Comment: Google Drive nor DropBox indicate when a file is downloaded.  You also would not be notified if another computer uploaded a file, and your session, sync that file.  The purpose of the notification is to indicate when the file upload is complete, that is all, it should not be considerd a security notification or a security feature.

Answer (score 2):

You don't know when files are downloaded, but you can sign out of all sessions except the current session. This will prevent others from using your account. You can also review your integrated applications and do not give them permission to use either service.

Below are links on how to protect your accounts.

[Remotely Sign Out from Gmail & Google Drive](http://web.archive.org/web/20160609162018/http://teachingforward.net/2014/06/27/remotely-sign-out-from-gmail-google-drive/)

[How can I protect my Dropbox account?](http://web.archive.org/web/20160609162024/https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/1973)